# Does tropylium chloride exist in ionic form or does it exist as a covalent molecule?

Tags: aromatic-compounds

My teacher taught me that in tropylium chloride, the chlorine atom posses negative charge to make the ring aromatic.
I wonder that then will this compound will exist in ionic form due to very high polarity or will it exist as covalent molecule only?

Comment: *Tropylium bromide was deduced to be a salt by Doering and Knox in 1954 by analysis of its infrared and ultraviolet spectra. The ionic structures of tropylium perchlorate and tropylium iodide  have been confirmed by X-ray crystallography.*  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropylium_cation)

Comment: https://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0365110X55002053

Answer (score 2):

The linked source in Mithoron's comment seems not to give a definitive answer, due to the instability/reactivity of the tropylium chloride/7-chloroheptatriene.

We do know that *hydroxy*-tropylium ($\text{cyclo-}\ce{C7H6OH^+}$) forms an ionic compound with chloride ion [[1]](https://doi.org/10.1107/S2053229617013183). The hydroxyl group is a pi donor, so this case is not exactly equivalent to a simple tropylium ion ring forming an ionic chloride.

**Reference**

1. Jandl C, Pöthig A (2017 Oct 1)."Hydroxytropylium chloride: the first crystal structure of an unfunctionalized hydroxytropylium ion". *Acta Crystallogr C Struct Chem.* **73**(Pt 10):810-813. doi: 10.1107/S2053229617013183. Epub 2017 Sep 27. PMID: 28978788.